# Powershell - Get root site and subsite information

Tags: 2013, powershell

I need to get the all site collection and subsite information. But for the properties , I need root site collection owner, subsite URL, subsite Name.

> Get-SPWebApplication | Get-SPSite -Limit all  | Get-SPWeb -Limit all |
>   Select Title, URL, Owner | Export-CSV "path" -NoTypeInformation

This script does not give me primary site collection owner name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A SPSite doesn't contain a Title property and a SPWeb doesn't have an Owner property. You need to split your PowerShell into two different execution rows, like this

```
Get-SPWebApplication | Get-SPSite -Limit all | Select URL, Owner
Get-SPWebApplication | Get-SPSite -Limit all | Get-SPWeb -Limit all | Select Title, URL
```

This might look strange, but the root site collection (SPSIte) also contain a SPWeb, where the Title property lives. That's why you'll get two result rows, one for the SPSite (with the owner) and one for the SPWeb (with the Title).

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
Get-SPSite -Limit All | 
  Get-SPWeb -Limit All | 
  where { $_.HasUniquePerm } | 
  foreach { $TTNweburl = $_.Url; $_ } | 
  Select -ExpandProperty Users | 
  Where { $_.IsSiteAdmin } | 
  Select {$TTNweburl}, UserLogin, DisplayName
```